# Extracion de Tablas con Preg_Mach

Tags: php, array, regex, preg-match

Hola necesito afinar este regex (`<tr><th>(.*?)<\/th\><\/tr\><td>(.*?)<\/td\><a href=\"(.*?)\"\>(Channel .*?)\<\/a\><\/td\>`)

Para Lograr este Arrive.:

Soccer,07/10 - 20:45,Portugal vs España,c3.php,Channel 3 Spanish

Soccer,07/10 - 20:45,Portugal vs España,c4.php,Channel 4 English

Soccer,07/10 - 20:45,Alemania vs Turquía,c5.php,Channel 5 English

Esta es la fuente:

```
 <tr><th>Soccer</th></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>07/10 - 20:45</td>
          <td>Portugal vs España</td>
          <td><a href="c3.php">Channel 3 Spanish</a></td>
          <td><a href="c4.php">Channel 4 English</a></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>07/10 - 20:45</td>
          <td>Alemania vs Turquía</td>
          <td></td>
          <td><a href="c5.php">Channel 5 English</a></td>
          <td><a href="c6.php">Channel 6 Latin</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><th>Roland Garros</th></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>07/10 - 11:00</td>
          <td>All Events</td>
          <td><a href="c1.php">Channel 1 Spanish</a></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: no queda claro qué preguntas. Por favor, provee un [mcve]

Comment: NO es una pregunta es una asistencia para lograr el arrive que meciono en el orden que necesito.

Comment: ¿Qué es una asistencia? ¿Qué es el arrive?

Comment: Por Favor si lees mi mensaje veras que tienes un Regex que he creado pero que no logro las expectativas para que cumpla con el Array que necesito.Y que necesito que alguien con mas experiencia en la creacion de REGEX me corrija el que he creado para que loque lo que necesito en el Array Gracias

Comment: Si bien se puede lograr con un regex bastante más complicado de lo que estás intentando, **no** es la manera. Te recomiendo leer http://php.net/manual/es/book.dom.php para manipular HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de Navegar en el interenet encontre una funcion que pude adaptar a mis necesidades aqui se las dejo para futuros usos :

```
function parseTable($html)
{
  // Find the table
  preg_match("/<table.*?>.*?<\/[\s]*table>/s", $html, $table_html);
//print_r($table_html);
  // Get title for each row
  preg_match_all("/<th.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*th>/", $table_html[0], $matches);
  $row_headers = $matches[1];

  // Iterate each row
  preg_match_all("/<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*tr>/s", $table_html[0], $matches);

  $table = array();

  foreach($matches[1] as $row_html)
  {
      
      
    preg_match_all("/<td.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*td>/", $row_html, $td_matches);
    
    $row = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($td_matches[1]); $i++)
    {
        $td=html_entity_decode($td_matches[1][$i]);
//      $td = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($td_matches[1][$i]));
        $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $td;
    }

    if(count($row) > 0)
      $table[] = $row; 

  }

  return $table;
```